# Building a Notification Engine using Server Sent Event

Tags: messaging, server-sent-events

In my new project, we are planning to design an embedded notification-system. In our application, we are having many users and one user can send messages to another user. In the receiver side, if he/she is logged-in in the website, then he/should get a notification in a bottom-right corner like the below image(which is similar to Gmail notification).
[image]

For this, I am planning to use Server-Sent Event(SSE), wherein the front-end application should listen to an end-point which emits new updates once it receives any updates from the Event-Bus. Using that response frontend would able to show the notification. Here is my architecture for that.

[image]

But before going into the implementation I am having the following the questions

1. Currently, using the Server-sent Event I can't able to group the messages. If there are messages of similar types I don't want to show multiple notifications. **So how do I able to group the messages in this architecture?**
2. What will happen, if there are too many clients opens the connection, would this implementation end-up in `Too many connections errors` issue?